# How to properly ask an input from user in LispWorks?

Tags: input, lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I have this code:

```
(defvar x)
(setq x (read))
(format t "this is your input: ~a" x)
```

It kinda work in Common Lisp but LispWorks it is showing this error:

```
End of file while reading stream #<Synonym stream to
*BACKGROUND-INPUT*>.
```

I mean I tried this: [How to read user input in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171913/how-to-read-user-input-in-lisp) of making a function. But still shows the same error.

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Common Lisp is a langauge, not an implementation. LispWorks is an implementation of Common Lisp. If you post an error, you need to give us a reproducible test case and how you ran your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wrote these three lines into Editor and then compiled it.

So, you can write this function into Editor:

```
(defun get-input ()
  (format t "This is your input: ~a" (read)))
```

Compile Editor and call this function from Listener (REPL).

```
CL-USER 6 > (get-input)
5
This is your input: 5
NIL
```

You can also use `*query-io*` stream like this:

```
(format t "This is your input: ~a" (read *query-io*))
```

If you call this line in Listener, it behaves like `read`. If you call it in Editor, it shows small prompt "Enter something:".

As you can see, no global variable was needed. If you need to do something with that given value, use [let](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm), which creates local bindings:

```
(defun input-sum ()
  (let ((x (read *query-io*))
        (y (read *query-io*)))
    (format t "This is x: ~a~%" x)
    (format t "This is y: ~a~%" y)
    (+ x y)))
```

Consider also using [read-line](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_lin.htm#read-line), which takes input and returns it as string:

```
CL-USER 19 > (read-line)
some text
"some text"
NIL

CL-USER 20 > (read-line)
5
"5"
NIL
```